# Angular material md-select-header issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

i have below code

```
<md-select class="" name="partners" ng-model="obj.con" data-md-container-class="selectdemoSelectHeader"
ng-disabled="notEditable('partners')">
    <md-select-header class="demo-select-header">
        <input ng-model="mdSelectHeader.searchTerm1" type="search" placeholder="{{'SEARCH' | T}}" class="demo-header-searchbox md-text">
    </md-select-header>
    <md-option ng-repeat="z in _.find(partnerContactList, { 'id': obj.par*1 }).contacts | filter:mdSelectHeader.searchTerm1" value="{{z.name}}">{{z.name}} ({{z.phone}},{{z.email}})</md-option>
</md-select>
```

I have no idea why the  unable to type anything.

Another code in the same page could work if the control is rendered dynamically.

For example, if i use ng-if or ng-repeat to render the control dynamically, the input field cannot type anything, otherwise, it could work.

Anyone has fix on it?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `value="{{z.name}}"` to `ng-value="z.name"`.

Comment: still the same, the problem is that i cannot input anything at the md-select-header's input text field

Comment: @SKLTFZ what version of angularjs are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this is a known issue with angular material library. However, there'a also a workaround in this [discussion](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9321) by using `$event.stopPropagation()` with angular built-in keydown.

```
<md-select class="" name="partners" ng-model="obj.con" data-md-container-class="selectdemoSelectHeader"
ng-disabled="notEditable('partners')">
    <md-select-header class="demo-select-header">
        <input ng-model="mdSelectHeader.searchTerm1" type="search" placeholder="{{'SEARCH' | T}}" class="demo-header-searchbox md-text" ng-keydown="$event.stopPropagation()">
    </md-select-header>
    <md-option ng-repeat="z in _.find(partnerContactList, { 'id': obj.par*1 }).contacts | filter:mdSelectHeader.searchTerm1" value="{{z.name}}">{{z.name}} ({{z.phone}},{{z.email}})</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Here's a working [sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rwOZLO)

Comment: thanks, im new to angularJS and i finally knew why people adding ng-keydown="$event.stopPropagation()" :p

Comment: what version of angularjs are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. I'm maintaining a legacy project which has Angular 1.6.4. Your suggestion had already been applied on searchboxes but it works on one production server and not the other. Kind of lost here :)